# Homeomorphism from uniform convergence topology to compact-convergence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Following-up on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3772297/gap-between-the-uniform-and-uniform-convergence-on-compacts-topologies/3772334#3772334), let $C(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ be respectively equipped with the topology of compact-convergence and uniform convergence, respectively.

The [Anderson-Kadec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem) theorem guarantees that these spaces are indeed homeomorphic.  Is it possible to explicitly describe this homeomorphism?  Is it simply
$$
f(x)\mapsto f(x)e^{-\|x\|},
$$
or something similar?

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple explicit description, though I doubt it. But the map you describe (or something similar) does not work: Let $f$ be a suitable bump function (say a standard Gaussian) and $f_n=e^{n}f(\cdot-n)$. Then $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on compact sets, but $\|f_n e^{-\|\cdot\|}\|_\infty\geq 1$.

Comment: Also, such a homeomorphism will certainly not be linear.

Comment: True, I think I was thinking that $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ can be covered by $\{f e^{-\beta \|x-\alpha\|}:\, f \in C(\mathbb{R}),\, \alpha\in \mathbb{R},\beta >0\}$ which is a different thing...